# locally finitely presented $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules are quasi-coherent

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ a scheme. Why do localy finitely presented $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules are quasi-coherent? Does my explaination is correct: one has locally on an open $U$,
$$ \mathcal{O}_U^m\to \mathcal{O}_U^n\to\mathcal{F}_{|U}\to 0 $$
so that $\mathcal{F}_{|U}\simeq\mathcal{O}_U^n/\text{Im}(g)$ with $g:\mathcal{O}_U^m\to\mathcal{O}_U^n$, but if $U=\text{Spec}(A)$ one has $\mathcal{O}_U^n=\widetilde{A^n}$ and I guess that the image $\text{Im}(g)=\widetilde{N}$ with $N$ a sub $A$-module of $A^n$ so that $\mathcal{F}_{|U}=\widetilde{A^n/N}$.

In general why locally generated $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules are not quasi-coherent? Here one has locally $f:\mathcal{O}_X^n\to\mathcal{F}_{|U}$ an epimorphism so that $\mathcal{F}_{|U}=\widetilde{A^n}/\text{ker}(f)$. The key point is then: image between quasi-coherent sheaf stay quasi-coherent (here $\text{Im}(g)$) but kernel of (quasi-coherent)$\to$($\mathcal{O}_X$-module) is not always quasi-coherent? Correct?

Comment: Here's another thread about this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1599980/622592
The property you give above is historically taken to be the *definition* of a quasi-coherent module: see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01BD

Comment: Ok, the key point is exactness of global section functor on affine space.